# Qt copying files

Tags: qt

I'm using **qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw492-5.5.0** on two different machines.

My problem is when it comes to copying files after the build using the following command:

```
copyfiles.commands += @call xcopy /S /Y /I $${THIRDPARTY_PATH}\\ffmpeg\\Windows\\* $${DESTDIR_WIN}\\debug
```

My first machine has Visual Studio 2013 but i'm using mingw.  This one properly uses the copyfiles.

On my second machine I dont have Visual Studio and when I run the build I get the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/sh: @call: command not found
```

I'm not sure why the same Qt install gives two different solutions.  I looked at the build steps of the project and both project are the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that you have a 'sh.exe' in your PATH on the second machine.

When generating Makefile's, qmake tries to be clever and determines whether it's running from Windows command line (cmd.exe), or from the Unix/Cygwin shell (sh.exe) by checking whether 'sh.exe' is in the current PATH. If it thinks it is running in a Unix shell it well generate a Makefile meant for mingw32-make, otherwise a Makefile meant for nmake.

This test is unfortunately pretty bogus nowadays, mostly because sh.exe is in part of the 'bin' directory of git on Windows. If this is your problem, and you're using git, just make sure that you include the 'cmd' directory of git instead.

Comment: Yes im using Git also.  You say make sure that you include the 'cmd' directory.  Would I remove the 'bin' directory of git? Or just append to the cmd to the path also?

Comment: OK I was able to solve it.  And git was the problem.  Thank you for the tip